# Packaging a Python project and its associated IPython magic extension

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic, python-poetry

I am in the process of deploying to Pypi a Python project, let's call it `foobar`. I would like to distribute it with a shell command **and** an IPython magic command. I use Poetry, and the relevant part of my `.toml` configuration file is:

```
  [tool.poetry.scripts]
  foobar = 'foobar.cli:main'
  foobar_magic = 'foobar.magic:load_ipython_extension'
```

After uploading this to TestPypi and installing it with `pip`, the shell command (`foobar`) works as expected. However, executing `%load_ext foobar_magic` in a Jupyter Notebook fails with:

```
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foobar_magic'
```

According to the [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/index.html#writing-extensions):

> You can put your extension modules anywhere you want, as long as they can be imported by Python’s standard import mechanism.

Under the same notebook, I have verified that `!foobar` and `import foobar` both work. How can I make `foobar_magic` be found too?

Moreover, although I'm not there yet, I guess the suffix of the entry point is wrong too. Indeed, the function I specify after the `:` will be called with no arguments, but the function `load_ipython_extension()` expects an IPython instance.

So I feel completely lost, and can't find any relevant documentation for deploying IPython Notebook extensions.

---

**Edit 1.** `%load_ext foobar.magic` unexpectedly works, and the magic `%foobar`  does not complain about the arguments. I don't understand why, and why it is `%foobar` and not `%foobar_magic` as declared.

**Edit 2.** the `foobar_magic = ...` stuff is ignored or useless. Suppressing it has no consequence on `%load_ext foobar.magic`. I think the latter invocation might be ok. But it's a little annoying not to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround:

1. Delete the line `foobar_magic = ...` of my `.toml`.
2. Move the contents of `foobar/magic.py` to `foobar/__init__.py` (originally empty), guarded with the following two lines:

   ```
   import sys
   if "ipykernel" in sys.modules:
      # magic stuff
   ```
3. This file being executed each time the module is imported, it is now enough to do (under a notebook):

   ```
   %load_ext foobar
   ```

   The guard ensures the magic stuff is executed if and only if foobar is imported from IPython.

This does not answer my original question, and I still do not fully understand how these entry points are supposed to work, but I am happy with the actual result.